# Browser opens default sample project not the one I'm working on

Tags: browser, gramex

I tried following the guided tutorial, but each time the browser opens to the default sample project provided and not the index.html file I created.
Any solutions for this?

Comment: Could you please share the directory where you're running Gramex and the directory of the index.html you're editing, please? They might be different.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.